# PHP: use an array in a select where condition

Tags: php, arrays, json

Through the string `$codear = $_POST ['codestring'];` data recovery, in json format, coming from a form. It returns me the following string array.

```
Array
(
[0] => 1071bf
[1] => 19d7f9
[2] => 16d78f
[3] => 110bf5
[4] => 10731e
[5] => 107155
[6] => 107124
[7] => 114c25
[8] => 1398c4
[9] => 189b95
[10] => 137521
)
```

These are product codes that I would like to use in a SELECT with condition, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE hotel_basic_price = $codear
```

Please note that this string varies in the number of products to each request sent by the user.

I also tried to use json_decode, in the form `$json = json_decode($codear, true);` but I get an error of `json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in`.

How should I handle this string in my Select?

Comment: The [PHP Manual for implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) you should find it useful in this situation. And the Manual for all situations

Comment: You may also find Google or the SO search facility useful as well

Comment: What interface are you using? `mysql_*`, `mysqli_*`, `PDO`? I assume `mysqli_*` based on previous questions.